# Realistic Rusty Chain

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, node-editor

I was doing [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZxmRyBUBJg). I think the UV unwrapping in the tutorial is not done well. I think the UV map should look like this

[image]

But these top and bottom views show that I have done something wrong. Either in my UV unwrapping or in my node map.

[image]

[image]

The top view shows much more "rust" than the bottom view. This is why I think I have done something wrong with this "rust" image texture.

Here is my node map

[image]

How to make a realistic rusty chain link ? What should I do better ?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's clear from the pictures what is wrong with those top and bottom pictures. Please edit your question with a description of what you think it is meant to look like and what specifically is wrong with those images.

Comment: You have two options: use seamless texture and unwrap chain to the edge of it for eliminate seams visibility. Second option (I always prefer) is make full procedural materials. Just use 3 noise textures - 1st in small size for iron detail bump, 2nd in small size for rusty detail bump. Now you create two different materials: iron and Rust. Use 3rd noise texture in bigger size for a mix this two materials. EDIT: in this case don't give sense use image texture, because noise texture give you very similar pattern. Only play with values.

Comment: @RayMairlot I edited the question and added a .blend file with the textures packed.

Comment: A seam is slightly visible around the chain link. This is due to the marked seams. You can retouch that with texture paint and a clone brush (strength set to 1). This method can also be useful to add rust where you want.

Comment: @Shubol3D I don't have any experience with procedural materials. I can try but maybe you can post your answer with a little more detail ?

Comment: @ Old Man : I'm really sorry, I'm busy now for make tutorial. But also I'm glad to help. I find this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8CmR_5KXFo    It is relative simple fundamentals
 and can be amazing time saver.  No image texture = no seams, no unwraping and work for any object and can adapt to almost any shape. You only combine generated textures and use it for your benefit. I really recommend spend time and study this feature. You save this time many times in future :-)

Comment: @Shubol3D No problem, thanks a lot. I will try the procedural textures. Is is time that I learn that skill too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seams are visible around the link at the lines corresponding to the UV seams :

[image]

To correct that, you can paint (texture paint) this part using the clone brush, preferably using a strength of 1 (if not you will have more blurry painting).

To clone paint, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> at the position you want to clone, then paint along the seam :

[image]

Note that will change your texture. So make a copy of it before you do that.

For adding more rusty parts, you can use the same principle, both in order to have more rust at the places you want and also to correct the seams :

[image]

The same part, before and after (no need to be an artist to do that !):

[image]

Edit : to have more rust in a more easy way (but that will not correct the seam problem) you can move the UV map parts to the center. In this particular case, that will not have any impact for the other texture :

[image]

Comment: Thanks @lemon ...do you think there are some errors in my UV unwrapping and/or node map ? Why is the bottom view not very "rusty" ?

Comment: @OldMan, This is because the uv map parts seen from the bottom view are on the top and bottom of the rusty texture : these parts of the texture have much more alpha than the center (which itself corresponds to the top of your mesh). For the unwrapping this is ok I think. Probably you used Blender without touching it after that and that guaranty the best surface proportionality for the faces. A trick could be to mark the seams inside the link (and not outside) because this is generally less visible, like for the seams of clothes in the principle (but painting is necessary too).

Comment: @OldMan, concerning the nodes setup, something to try : having the rusty parts less glossy than the other parts.