# Mapping of metal rust textures on UV sphere

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to get a tileable texture on a uv sphere. It should look something like this:

[image]

But in my blend file it looks like this:

[image]

What I did is create the UV sphere and when I created the UV Sphere I had "generate UV's" checked.This is how the UV map looks like when doing that:

[image]

I thought that there is no further need for uv unwrapping now. Then I added the material and the textures (created in Substance). This is the material:

[image]

How to get these textures right ?? I thought it should work after checking "Generate UV's" when adding the UV Sphere ? Is there a problem with my texture ? With my UV map ? Or is it the material setup ?

[image]

Comment: Your UV map is not good at least. Try to add new UV sphere (*shift+A*) with the same topology exactly in the same place while being in edit mode of the current sphere. Do not forget to check *Generate UVs* in Tool panel (*T*). Scale it a bit to match previous sphere and after that you can delete old sphere. All these operations should be made in edit mode. Messed UV will be also deleted while new automatically generated map will remain. Screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/rNNIB

Comment: You can try to use 'generated' instead of 'UV' in the texture coord input node. Then in all the texture nodes, use 'box' instead of 'flat'. And tune the 'blend' value at least for the base color texture node.

Comment: I added a complete new mesh and checked Generate UV's. Same problem. I also tried the solution suggested by Lemon but I did not manage to get the texture right.

Comment: I am using 2.78a version and *Generate UV* is working correctly. Post yours screenshot when you place new sphere like this: http://imgur.com/a/qVlr8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some more explanations about what I proposed in the comments.

The changes in the nodes setting:

- All come from 'generate'
- Texture nodes are set to 'box'
- A blend is tuned to avoid to see the 'box borders' (maybe, you should prefer to link them all with a single value)
- The UV map is removed from the normal map node to keep coherency regarding the texture

[image]

So when the material is changed to that:

[image]

**But** the blending of the 'box' mode looses a bit of the quality.

**Edit: some explanations following the comments**

The sphere cannot be unwrapped equally (respecting model vs. UV map proportions) without seams.

But if you have seams, that will be visible at the junction on the 3D model (even if we have seen a solution here [Realistic Rusty Chain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60347/realistic-rusty-chain/60350#60350), the problem is your texture is repainted so is no more generic).

So we don't want seams. But without seams no respect of proportions...

The box mapping (as I imagine it works):

It is a cube envelop projected on the surface. And... that makes seams.
But we have the ability to use the blend factor, which is some way extends the envelop so that parts overlap but are blended.

So all seems to be good... except the point I mentioned before: we loose a bit of quality due to this blending.

Comment: hi Lemon, could you explain what you think is the problem and why this is a good solution ? Did you also consider other solutions ? By the way, I think it works ;)

Comment: Hi @OldMan. Answer edited

Comment: So you say either have seams and you will have to repaint or you will have no seams but problems with proportions ? I thought tileable textures should be the answer ? I am confused now ...

Comment: So seamless textures are not the solution ... Once you set seams you will always have the problem that seams are visible ? So it is procedural textures or mask/paint the seams ?

Comment: I think this is the exact same problem for earth map: poles are stretched to fit a rectangle. Yes, seamless textures are seamless on the border only. And yes procedural texture is a possibility.